# Trouble with ADF project call from external application

Tags: java, oracle-adf, backing-beans, facescontext

I have an **ADF** project using **jdeveloper** with name *ADF1* and has a self authentication with the welcome page **login.jspx** and its backing bean **backing_login.java**.

Now I need to use another application for authentication with name *AUTH1*.

The user will do the following:

1. The user will request login to *ADF1*
2. The user enters his username and password
3. The form posts to *AUTH1* and is redirected to ADF1 after successful authentication with a return URL. But it can't be the **login.jspx** because it will show again the login page.

Now this return URL must be what?

1. A bean (I don't know how to do this I need suggestions)
2. Another normal servlet in *ADF1*

I did the second option: but I can't seem to access the `FacesContext` because it's null in the servlet:

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ctx.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(ctx, null, "accessDirectPageOnline");
```

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I created another page **login-return.jspx** and created a `backing_bean` bound to it and now the problem is that the first load of the page, whatever redirect I do even in a `beforephase` method, which runs it successfully, it always redirects to **login.jspx** *I don't know why*, but in the second try of redirect it succeeds!

But I need it from the first time.

I think the problem is coming from the **ADF Security** procedure which forces the user with an obligatory **login** page, I don't know how to bypass that . . .

Comment: Are you using Tasks flow?

Comment: @Salman But I need to do some processes before going into the task flow. For that reason I needed some sort of bean or servlet to do the needed processes and then handleNavigation to the required task flow, Here it lies my problem . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this through creating a new view coming out from all star point of the flow.
I created a backing bean for it and calculated my operations there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Task Flow` then you can access any `Bounded Task Flow` by specifying the correct `URL`, then the `default activity` will be called for that `Bounded Task Flow`.

Check this link to know how form `Bounded Task Flow` `URL`: 
[URL Task Flow Call with HTTP POST Method](http://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.com/2013/07/url-task-flow-call-with-http-post-method.html)

Also, Checks this thread for more discussion: [Access Bounded Flow Directly From URL](https://community.oracle.com/message/4354496#4354496)

Comment: But I need to do some processes before going into the task flow. For that reason I needed some sort of bean or servlet to do the needed processes and then handleNavigation to the required task flow, Here it lies my problem . . .

Comment: you can make some bean class as default activity in the task flow using method call activity. check this link :https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/an_epic_question_how_to

Comment: simply go to the bean you want, then right click, select (Create Data Control). now you can see the bean's method in (Data Control) tab. After that you can drag and drop the method you want from the (Data Control) to the Task flow and mark it as default activity

Comment: But can I call a bounded task flow without passing through the default authentication? like the login page? will it permit?

Comment: Or an unbounded task flow?

Comment: I am not sure if you can access unbounded task flow in the same way, since there is now default activity in it. But, again I am not sure. you can ask in [Oracle Community OTN](https://community.oracle.com/community/developer/english)   there are professionals who can help you more in your issue.

Comment: I created another page login-return.jspx and created a backing_bean, and now he problem is that first time whatever I do it always redirects to login.jspx I don't know why, in the second try of redirect it succeeds!